# getting spring mvc model value with javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I tried whole things what I found on the internet but I failed about this. I investigated all issues on here or other sites but It didn't create any difference. I do something wrong but I can't see.

Now here is my jsp page :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" />"></script>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.css" />" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    debugger;
    var allEmployees = "${allEmployees}";
    debugger;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="table-responsive">
<h2>Tüm Çalışanlar</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <tr>
                <td class="field-label col-xs-3 active">
                    <label>TC No</label>
                </td>
                <td class="field-label col-xs-3 active">
                    <label>Ad</label>
                </td>
                <td class="field-label col-xs-3 active">
                    <label>Soyad</label>
                </td>
                <td class="field-label col-xs-3 active">
                    <label>Başlama Tarihi</label>
                </td>
                <td class="field-label col-xs-3 active">
                    <label>Maaş</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </div>
    <c:if test="${not empty allEmployees}">
        <c:forEach items="${allEmployees}" var="employee">
            <tr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <td>${employee.citizenNumber}</td>
                        <td>${employee.name}</td>
                        <td>${employee.surname}</td>
                        <td>${employee.joiningDate}</td>
                        <td>${employee.salary}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="<c:url value='/edit-${employee.oid}-employee' />">${employee.oid}</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="<c:url value='/delete-${employee.oid}-employee' />">delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

@Autowired
EmployeeService employeeService;

@RequestMapping(value = {"/","/list"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String lisEmployees(Model model){
    List<Employee> employees = employeeService.findAllEmployees();

    model.addAttribute("allEmployees",employees);

    return "allemployees";

  }
}
```

I debugged on firebug but I can't handle model value and here investigate my jsp pages html code I try to fill a table with model value but it can't fill. I debugged controller and employees list have a record and model have allEmployees key to mapped employees list.

So where am I wrong? How to I cope with this? Please, Could you help me?

Comment: Have you sen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508773/how-to-access-spring-mvc-model-object-in-javascript-file

Comment: Yes I have. But it doesn't help me. I tried.