# How to pass the database column to javascript function in jsp or html

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

How to pass the database column to javascript function in jsp or html

```
function forumQuestions(questions){
document.getElementById("questions").value = questions;
 document.getElementById("questions").submit();
```

}

```
<a href="javascript:forumQuestions()"><c:out value="${forumBean.questions}"></c:out></a></td>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access Spring MVC model object in javascript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508773/how-to-access-spring-mvc-model-object-in-javascript-file)

Comment: May not be using spring, but answer should be same principle

Comment: actually it is a forum page.... i retrieve the data from database... when i click on the data ... same content has to shown in other page thanks for your rply

Comment: how to pass the database column to javascript

Comment: I'm not sure what will show up from `<c:out value="${forumBean.questions}"></c:out>` but your best bet is to either make sure that it's a valid javascript value, or make it a JSON string and use `var data = JSON.parse(<c:out value="${forumBean.questions}" />);`, if it's not a proper javascript value without making it a JSON string, there will most likely be a syntax error in the console

Comment: i dont have knowledge in json can u get the solution for that by using javascript

Comment: I'm not sure I follow "get the solution ... using javascript", as for JSON, it's very simple: `"{ \"propertyName1\": VALUE, \"propertyName2\": VALUE }"`. [W3 Schools Introduction to JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp), I'm afraid I don't have much experience writing a Java backend, but there should be a way to get a JSON representation of `forumBean` that you can then use to set a javascript value... assuming that you have access to modify the Java side

Comment: http://localhost:888/ForumAnswers.jsp?Question=how%20are%20you? i get the content in address bar.. but how to show that how are you in other page

Comment: hey finally i got the solution... thanks for ur rply Patrick Barr